# Css transform scaleX with opacity not working in Safari

Tags: css, safari

Here is the [code](https://codepen.io/powerispower/pen/aPXYQW).

When scaleX with opacity are used in a background image, it does not work in safari on mac or in iphone, so we use scale or scale3d(sx,sy,sz) to resolve that,
but how does this happen? Is this a safari bug?

```
        @keyframes scale-not-work-in-iphone {
    0% {
        transform: scaleX(1);
    }
    99% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale3d(2, 2, 2);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I Think it is because you didn't use prefixes for webkit. Also you could set the opacity at 0% to be sure it is passed. Hope this helped.

```
@keyframes scale-should-work-in-iphone {
    0% {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform:scaleX(1) scale3d(2, 2, 2);
      -moz-transform:scaleX(1) scale3d(2, 2, 2);
      -ms-transform:scaleX(1) scale3d(2, 2, 2);
      -o-transform:scaleX(1) scale3d(2, 2, 2);
      transform: scaleX(1) scale3d(2, 2, 2);
    }
    99% {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform:scaleX(1) scale3d(2, 2, 2);
      -moz-transform:scaleX(1) scale3d(2, 2, 2);
      -ms-transform:scaleX(1) scale3d(2, 2, 2);
      -o-transform:scaleX(1) scale3d(2, 2, 2);
      transform: scaleX(1) scale3d(2, 2, 2);
    }

    100% {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform:scaleX(1) scale3d(0, 0, 0);
      -moz-transform:scaleX(1) scale3d(0, 0, 0);
      -ms-transform:scaleX(1) scale3d(0, 0, 0);
      -o-transform:scaleX(1) scale3d(0, 0, 0);
      transform:scaleX(1) scale3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Safari has not needed vendor prefixes for this in many years--since before version 3.1 at least. Neither has any other browser.